# .NET Core Web API XML with DTD parsing error

Tags: c#, xml, dtd, doctype, asp.net-core-webapi

I am integrating middleware API service that takes the XML request, parses the XML, then sends it to WorldPay XML API. The app is developed in .NET Core.

I have made classes that matches the XML, and am using the class as input parameter in the controller's endpoint.

Based on [WorldPay XML API docs](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/gg/corporate-gateway-guide/content/directintegration/paymentrequests.htm), the valid request is in format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//Worldpay//DTD Worldpay PaymentService v1//EN"
  "http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="YOUR_MERCHANT_CODE"> <!--Enter your own merchant code-->
  <submit>
    <order orderCode="YOUR_ORDER_CODE"> <!--Enter a unique order code each time-->
      <description>YOUR DESCRIPTION</description> <!--Enter a description useful to you-->
      <amount currencyCode="GBP" exponent="2" value="5000"/>
      <paymentDetails>
        <CARD-SSL>
          <cardNumber>4444333322221111</cardNumber>
          <expiryDate><date month="01" year="2020"/></expiryDate> 
          <cardHolderName>A Shopper</cardHolderName>
          <cardAddress>
            <address>
              <address1>47A</address1>
              <postalCode>CB94BQ</postalCode>
              <city>Cambridge</city>
              <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
            </address>
          </cardAddress>
        </CARD-SSL>
        <session shopperIPAddress="123.123.123.123" id="0215ui8ib1" /> 
      </paymentDetails>
      <shopper>
        <shopperEmailAddress>ashopper@myprovider.com</shopperEmailAddress>
      </shopper>
    </order>
  </submit>
</paymentService>
```

The API endpoints should be 1:1 with WorldPay API endpoints. The service should modify the merchant code to be the merchant code the service is using, obfuscate sensitive data, log/track it and send a request to WorldPay.

The issue I am having is that with the class I made as the parameter in endpoint is null if the request XML contains !DOCTYPE in it. If I remove the !DOCTYPE, and information in it, the XML is parsed well and the object as parameter is valid.

My endpoint in swagger looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<paymentService>
  <submit>
    <order>
      <description>string</description>
      <amount>
        <currencyCode>string</currencyCode>
        <exponent>string</exponent>
        <value>string</value>
      </amount>
      <paymentDetails>
        <cardssl>
          <cardNumber>string</cardNumber>
          <expiryDate>
            <date>
              <month>string</month>
              <year>string</year>
            </date>
          </expiryDate>
          <cardHolderName>string</cardHolderName>
          <cardAddress>
            <address>
              <address1>string</address1>
              <postalCode>string</postalCode>
              <city>string</city>
              <countryCode>string</countryCode>
            </address>
          </cardAddress>
        </cardssl>
        <session>
          <shopperIPAddress>string</shopperIPAddress>
          <id>string</id>
        </session>
      </paymentDetails>
      <shopper>
        <shopperEmailAddress>string</shopperEmailAddress>
      </shopper>
      <orderCode>string</orderCode>
    </order>
  </submit>
  <version>string</version>
  <merchantCode>string</merchantCode>
</paymentService>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its likely its not parsing the XML as its not valid against the DTD.

The XML you are creating is not valid as you not marking up the interface to tell it what's an element and what's an attribute for example orderCode is being rendered as an element not an attribute.

I guess you need your interface to look something like this

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string orderCode { get; set; }
```

or

```
[XmlAttribute("orderCode")]
public string OrderCode { get; set; }
```

Before you put the DTD back in ensure your XML is valid have a look at https://liquid-technologies.com/online-xml-validator

Comment: That's a bug with swagger representation of XML, my classes are properly marked with [XmlAttribute]/[XmlElement]